# How do I facet filter on a negative number?

Tags: algolia

I am trying facet/filter on an attribute that has integer values. Positive values work fine, but Algolia is treating the [minus sign as negation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/filtering/?language=laravel#facet-filters) instead of part of the value.

So for the filter:

`facetFilters: "category_id:-1`

it returns all records that have a category_id other than `1`.

I've tried quoting the value `category_id:'-1'` without luck. Is there a way to escape or disable the negation on facet filters to allow for filtering on negative values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your facet value starts with a '-' then you can escape the character with a \ to prevent the engine from interpreting this as a negative facet filter.

For example, filtering on category_id:-1 will filter on all records that have a category_id equal to “-1”.